# PostgreSQL/pgAdmin4 ERROR: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "index"

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, constraints, unique

I'm trying to transform my MySQL design to PostgreSQL but when I try to create the table "index":

```
CREATE TABLE  "model1"."index" (
  "id_index" INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ,
  "index_name" VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
  "index_type_id_index_type" INT  NOT NULL,
  "index_provider_id_index_provider" INT  NOT NULL,
  "miseq" VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  "nextseq" VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ("id_index"),
  CONSTRAINT "fk_index_index_type"
    FOREIGN KEY ("index_type_id_index_type")
    REFERENCES "model1"."index_type" ("id_index_type")
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT "fk_index_index_provider"
    FOREIGN KEY ("index_provider_id_index_provider")
    REFERENCES "model1"."index_provider" ("id_index_provider")
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION);
```

I got this error: ERROR: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "index".

The two tables containing the foreign keys were created before the "index" table:

```
CREATE TABLE  "model1"."index_type" (
  "id_index_type" INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ,
  "name" VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ("id_index_type"));

CREATE TABLE  "model1"."index_provider" (
  "id_index_provider" INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ,
  "name" VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ("id_index_provider"));
```

Comment: Somewhere else you are trying to create a foreign key that references the `"index"` table. The code you have shown will not result in this error. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=8ff54bd2dc2001a26e62fcbe7ceef271

Comment: Maybe it's an intermediate table. Do intermediate tables work different in PostgreSQL?

Comment: I have no idea what "intermediate" table is supposed to be. Do you mean a "temporary" table? But you will need to show us your **complete** code in order to help you finding the root cause of that error. The code you have shown has no problems

Comment: I refer to a table to represent a N:M relationship. The error was in this table, now is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The error was in another table as @a_horse_with_no_name suggested.